# How can I use Apache cxf-2.4.8.jar as dependency of my war project and not exo.ws.rest.core-2.3.3-GA that is installed in of JBoss 7?

Tags: apache

I am migrating to GateIn 3.6( JBOSS7) . The following error occurs since my project war have a dependancy with exo.ws.rest.core-2.3.3-GA since it is deployed in JBOSS7(GateIn3.6)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

18:36:02,711 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.myfaces.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getProperty(PropertyResolverImpl.java:457)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  ... 302 more

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1) Caused by: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientWebApplicationException: java.lang.NullPointerException

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.handleResponse(WebClient.java:839)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:816)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:743)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:717)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:344)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.get(WebClient.java:469)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at com.radiant.cisms.services.WorkflowProcessService.getBusinessRuleList(WorkflowProcessService.java:489)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at com.radiant.cisms.services.WorkflowProcessService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$b715c2f2.invoke()

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:700)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at com.radiant.cisms.services.WorkflowProcessService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$14154f1.getBusinessRuleList()

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at com.radiant.cisms.view.bean.BusinessRuleBean.getBusinessRuleList(BusinessRuleBean.java:69)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  ... 307 more

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.exoplatform.services.rest.impl.ResponseImpl$ResponseBuilderImpl.(ResponseImpl.java:217)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.exoplatform.services.rest.impl.ResponseImpl$ResponseBuilderImpl.clone(ResponseImpl.java:284)

18:36:02,727 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.setResponseBuilder(AbstractClient.java:381)

18:36:02,742 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.handleResponse(WebClient.java:829)

18:36:02,742 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8087-1)  ... 322 more

expecting a solution...

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in gatein [pom.xml](https://github.com/gatein/gatein-portal/blob/3.6.x/pom.xml) the version of exo.ws used by Gatein 3.6.x is

```
    <org.exoplatform.ws.version>2.3.4-GA</org.exoplatform.ws.version>
```

So I think upgrading your dependency on exo.ws could resolve your problem.

Romain